# Mailchimp API post members batch operation

Tags: java, jax-rs, batch-processing, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I find that when I submit a batch operation to the Mailchimp API for adding members to a Mailchimp audience, the operations fail with this error...

```
[{\"field\":\"email_address\",\"message\":\"This value should not be blank.\"}]
```

This is odd because my batch operations specify the email_addresses.

```
        ArrayList<MailchimpOperation> operations = new ArrayList<MailchimpOperation>();
    for (Contact contact : contacts) {
        MailchimpOperation operation = new MailchimpOperation();
        operation.method = "POST";
        operation.path = "lists/" + audienceid + "/members";
        NewMember newMember = new NewMember();
        newMember.email_address = contact.email;
        MergeFields mf = new MergeFields();
        mf.FNAME = contact.firstname;
        mf.LNAME = contact.lastname;
        newMember.merge_fields = mf;
        newMember.status = "subscribed";
        operation.body = newMember.toString();
        operation.operation_id = "add_batch_" + batchNumber + "_to_mailchimp_audience_" + audienceid;
        operations.add(operation);
    }
```

I saw in some stack overflow posts that operation.body should be a JSON object. I have tried this as well...

```
ArrayList<MailchimpOperation> operations = new ArrayList<MailchimpOperation>();
    for (Contact contact : contacts) {
        MailchimpOperation operation = new MailchimpOperation();
        operation.method = "POST";
        operation.path = "lists/" + audienceid + "/members";
        NewMember newMember = new NewMember();
        newMember.email_address = contact.email;
        MergeFields mf = new MergeFields();
        mf.FNAME = contact.firstname;
        mf.LNAME = contact.lastname;
        newMember.merge_fields = mf;
        newMember.status = "subscribed";
        operation.body = newMember;
        operation.operation_id = "add_batch_" + batchNumber + "_to_mailchimp_audience_" + audienceid;
        operations.add(operation);
    }
```

This yields the error...

```
Mailchimp error: The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.,mailchimp error 1 Schema describes string, object found instead,mailchimp error 2 Schema describes string, object found instead
```

And if I explicitly set operation.body like this, the operations succeed...

```
operation.body = "{\"merge_fields\":{\"FNAME\":\"" + contact.firstname + "\",\"LNAME\":\""
                + contact.lastname + "\"}, \"email_address\":\"" + contact.email + "\", \"status\":\"subscribed\"}";
```

So why does my first approach where I set `operation.body = newMember.toString()` fail?

Comment: Not sure where the NewMember object is coming from, does it have a string representation or json output method ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to not use .toString(), but rather this...

```
    operation.body = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(newMember);
```